# Error running Angular 6 SPA

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to create a new Angular 6 SPA using Visual Studio 2017 Community.

However when I runt he project I am getting the following error;

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> NodeInvocationException: rxjs.merge is not a function
>
> TypeError: rxjs.merge is not a function
>   at new ApplicationRef (webpack://%5Bname%5D_%5Bhash%5D/./node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js?:6758:18)

When running `webpack --config .\webpack.config.vendor.js --mode development`

I get the following output;

```
    Hash: ce0f0762f3389ba7924e2d2c28b9e665b99678a4
Version: webpack 4.2.0
Child
    Hash: ce0f0762f3389ba7924e
    Time: 4181ms
    Built at: 2018-3-21 21:35:28
         Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
     vendor.js  5.27 MiB  vendor  [emitted]  vendor
    vendor.css   174 KiB  vendor  [emitted]  vendor
    Entrypoint vendor = vendor.js vendor.css

    WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
    7498:15-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
     @ ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
     @ dll vendor

    WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
    7518:15-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
     @ ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
     @ dll vendor

    WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
    System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
    For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
     @ dll vendor 7498:15-36

    WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
    System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
    For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
     @ dll vendor 7518:15-102
    Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css:
        Entrypoint undefined = extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename
Child
    Hash: 2d2c28b9e665b99678a4
    Time: 4160ms
    Built at: 2018-3-21 21:35:28
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    vendor.js  5.3 MiB  vendor  [emitted]  vendor
    Entrypoint vendor = vendor.js

    WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js
    System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
    For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
     @ dll vendor 7539:15-36

    WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js
    System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
    For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
     @ dll vendor 7559:15-102
```

and when running `webpack --mode development` i get the following output;

```
    webpack : (node:22080) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
At line:1 char:1
+ webpack --mode development
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ((node:22080) De....hooks` instead:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Hash: e69114918ff049b5c0ac707c222d6ee8afd2d94a
Version: webpack 4.2.0
Child
    Hash: e69114918ff049b5c0ac
    Time: 7313ms
    Built at: 2018-3-21 21:37:47
                 Asset      Size       Chunks             Chunk Names
        main-client.js   230 KiB  main-client  [emitted]  main-client
    main-client.js.map  2.54 KiB  main-client  [emitted]  main-client
    Entrypoint main-client = main-client.js main-client.js.map
Child
    Hash: 707c222d6ee8afd2d94a
    Time: 7950ms
    Built at: 2018-3-21 21:37:48
             Asset     Size       Chunks             Chunk Names
    main-server.js  3.3 MiB  main-server  [emitted]  main-server
    Entrypoint main-server = main-server.js
```

My package.json file is as follows;

```
{
  "name": "Bemfeito.Services.Public",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0-rc.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.10.2",
    "@types/chai": "4.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.5",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "4.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "chalk": "2.3.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.7",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "3.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.2.0",
    "popper.js": "1.14.1",
    "preboot": "6.0.0-beta.3",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.7",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-addons": "^1.1.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.12",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.21.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  }
}
```

Now the only other point to mention is that in the solution explorer I have a few warnings on webpack-cli which I am not sure whether I need all the packages listed? Below is a screenshot of this;

[image: Picutre of npm issues from visual studio 2017]

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what happening here?

Comment: Angular v6 requires rxjs v6. Did you try to update it? Then, also in your code you should use rxjs v6 syntax.

Comment: I have a similar issue but in `boot.server.ts` at `appRef.isStable.first(isStable => isStable)`. The error is stating that first is not existing. Any idea?

Comment: I fixed the error by replacing the that line with `appRef.isStable.pipe`

Comment: @iAziz I have been searching for that answer for hours.  I followed the Angular upgrade guide perfectly, used the rxjs-lint tools, and more.  Bless you.  Please take the credit you deserve and post that as the answer here!  (That will also help others who may think this question is unanswered.)

Comment: @iAziz we did that too, but we used appRef.isStable.pipe(first(obj => {..})); -> so we only consume the first item

Comment: Are you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by replacing the that line with **appRef.isStable.pipe**